# How to change the language of the dynamic content in android

Tags: java, android

I have to do this:

- user should be able to enter text to create post - "create a post " button
- these post should be viewed in a wall.
- Based on chosen languages, static contents as well as dynamic contents on the app should change accordingly. It should be available in the settings screen of the app.

I have a problem that how to change the language of the content view on MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can change static content like this.
First create string file based on the language.
when change language execute this method

```
 public void changeLang(String lang)
{
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    //getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    updateTexts();

  }

private void updateTexts()
    {
    //update text of label in here.
   textLabel.setText(R.string.welcome);

    }
```

next overide the configuration change method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (myLocale != null){
        newConfig.locale = myLocale;
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

I have no idea about dynamic content. I think it will not be possible. But if you have content with other langage you can load that when change language.